# Will Apple automatically reject an iOS app that disables the touch screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I understand that the Apple Review Guidelines state that an app which alters the switches (volume up/down and mute switches) will be rejected, but what about the touch screen functionality? Will Apple immediately reject an app which locks the screen (temporarily, for express purpose in the app, obviously) or is this allowed? I've not seen explicit documentation either way.

Comment: Depends on what you're locking the screen for.  If you just want to show a loading indicator, that's perfectly fine, but if you want to take someone to the home screen, that's a big no-no.

Comment: @CodaFi No, I'm just one girl trying to make it in this crazy world. But thanks for entertaining the possibility!

Comment: No problem.  It's always nice to assume the worst on SO. ;P

Comment: the more you know. *shooting star* ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you use undocumented/private APIs, your app is immediately rejected. So if you're somehow programmatically triggering the same action that would happen if a user hit the lock button on the top of their iOS device, then yes, your app would be rejected.

I'm not aware of the scope of your app so I won't try to assume the purpose of the lock, but you could always create your own UIView that covers the entire screen.

Comment: No, I'm not looking to co-opt or program a screenlock. I think the UIView idea is more up my alley. Thanks for the speedy response.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean disabling touches for a period of time, that was the default behaviour of some animation (I say was, because UIView animation have change at some point, so you must check documentation for that aspect)
But to go back to the topic, Yes you can disable `User interaction` for a period of time, Apple do it, in transition for example. (that is for a very short period of time, but it's logical)
The reason you should get rejected while doing so would be because you use it in a way that is not natural for the user experience or not constant with the general `feel of use` of the devise.
But even if Apple don't reject you, `if` you are to `remove user interaction for no good reason` the `user will` just kill you app with the home button and `delete your app right away`, a least it's what I would do.

Comment: agreed. the app i have in mind would disable user interaction as a protective feature in a game app for young children.